# How to prevent writing new line while read line in bash

Tags: bash

The examplary code below writes hi in a new line at every iteration. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    var=$(echo $line | cut -d \, -f 2)
    echo -n " $var"
done < file.csv > output.txt
```

Desired output is a concatenation of '$var's at each iteration. The code is run in OS X.

[Resolved]
In most cases of similar problems, klashww's answer would be what you want to try so that I would accept it as the answer. Yet, in my case, such options all failed in fixing the bug. The behavior was due to non-displayed character '^M' at the end of each line, since the file was coming from windows. I relearned that we should make sure to get rid of '^M' before processing it in bash via the line below. After that, the original code works fine.

```
 tr -d '\015' < file > newfile
```

Comment: You can delete the `echo` call.  What behavior do you want to have?

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen  I think the problem is that hi is in a new line every time rather than the output being hihihihihihihi without newlines. I however cannot reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Interesting that it works for others. Was the input file csv?

Comment: "hi" actually worked for me too. I believe the issue is coming from that I am  using the part of imported 'line variable'. Just edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `echo "hi\c"` instead of `echo -n "hi"` or `printf` if avaliable , example `printf "hi"`.

In your example, this should work:

```
while read line; do
    var=$(echo $line | cut -d \, -f 2)
    printf " $var"
done < file.csv > output.txt
```

Or you can use a better tool:

```
awk -F\,  '{printf " "$2}' file.csv > output.txt
```

If everything fails `tr` brute force:

```
echo " $var"| tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Have edited the question. For this problem, echo -n "hi" and "hi\c" both did not work. I am currently guessing that I have to remove '\n' copied in the variable.

Comment: See my edited answer , especially  the ``awk`` part @villybyun

Comment: awk performs well in the exemplary data I have put. Yet, I am avoiding awk in the original code due to its looping behavior for every occurrence and other specific restraints.

Comment: I have tried _printf_ as well, but it did not work. As the 'hi' example works, my guess now is that 'var' is bringing the new line operator from .csv file. I cannot validate that my current searches do not tell me how to display non printing characters of string variable in bash. Searching more..

Comment: Then try ``echo " $var"| tr -d '\n'`` @villybyun

Comment: accepting this as the answer due to its comprehensiveness.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try using pure bash:

```
while IFS=',' read nu1 var nu2; do
    echo -n " $var"
done < file.csv > output.txt
```

`nu`: "not used"

Comment: Why is using IFS better in this case?

Comment: @villybyun:  IFS saves a couple of child processes.  I doubt that will perform significantly faster, but it depends partly on the number of loops.   For example, if you had 100 lines in the file, your code would create 200 child processes.  Using IFS would create none.  Secondly, the strange problem with a newline could have been coming from the output from `cut`.  I doubt it has any advantages over using `awk`.